# "Deconstruct assignment requires an expression with a type on the right hand side"

Tags: c#

The following code:

```cs
(object ret, Expression subexpr) = expr switch {

    // instance member
    MemberExpression mexpr when mexpr.Expression is not null =>
        (mexpr, mexpr.Expression),

    // instance method call
    MethodCallExpression callExpr when callExpr.Object is not null =>
        (callExpr, callExpr.Object),

    // include instance method calls, or static extension method calls
    MethodCallExpression callExpr when
            callExpr.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExtensionAttribute)).Any() &&
            callExpr.Arguments.FirstOrDefault() is not null =>
        (callExpr, callExpr.Arguments.First()),

    _ => (null, null)
};
```

does not compile, with:

> CS8131: Deconstruct assignment requires an expression with a type on the right-hand-side.

**Why is this happening? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a simple case of "the compiler can't figure out the type of the switch". If you replace the deconstruction with a simple `var x =` to let the compiler figure out what type the switch expressions should evaluate to, the error message changes to a much more useful:

> No best type was found for the switch expression

The tuples that you return each case are of type:

```
(MemberExpression, Expression)
(MethodCallExpression, Expression)
(MethodCallExpression, Expression)
```

The compiler probably can't decide what common ancestor of `MemberExpression` and `MethodCallExpression` it should use.

Even a simple "hint" like this,

```
((object)mexpr, mexpr.Expression),
```

or:

```
((Expression)mexpr, mexpr.Expression),
```

so that the compiler doesn't need to find common ancestors, fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `(null, null)`, use `(default(object), default(Expression))` in order to help the compiler to guess the types of your right-hand-side expression.

Comment: is `default` of these types going to be equivalent to a `null` though? would the implementation have to account for potential `null` checks in other scopes?

Comment: `default(object)` as an exmaple is equivalent to `null` with the difference that it's a "typed null" so it helps the compiler in various scenarios to figure out what's the intention of your code